# Request Multiple URL with Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am creating my first node app using ExpressJS and I am confused about how to requesting multiple url's using Request and async.  The code I have below spits out the following error, "chart1 is not defined".

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel([
    function(next) {
        apiRequestGoesHere(chart1, function(error) {
            request.get('http://203.33.33.44:8080/reports/43?type=0&key=fakekey'),
            next(null, firstData);
        });
    },
    function(next) {
        anotherApiRequest(chart2, function(error) {
            request.get('http://203.33.33.44:8080/reports/42?type=0&key=fakekey'),
            next(null, secondData);
        });
    }], 

    function(err, results, firstData, secondData) {
        // results is [firstData, secondData]
        res.render('index', {
             title: 'Home KP',
             firstData: chart1
        });
    });
});
```

Can someone please explain to me how to define these and get this working?

Comment: Mmm, this code doesn't define `chart1` or `chart2`. Where are they defined? I don't think this has anything to do with ExpressJS, you just haven't defined the variables or they are not accessible from this context

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is not defining `chart1` anywhere. Maybe you want to check `results[0]`?

With async.parallel, the `results` variable contains the results of all the functions, in the same order. When you call `next(null, firstData)`, you're telling async to put the value of `firstData` into the `results` array, and since that function is the first, it will go into `results[0]` (next one is `results[1]`, etc).